# OS Sampler V/S HTTP Request Sampler in JMeter

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I have to generate load for my performance testing using JMeter. I am having .Net code to send data to IOT hub which we want to use.
I can easily create REST endpoints or executable based on requirement. To integrate with JMeter which Sampler I should prefer OS Sampler or HTTP request Sampler to integrate with existing .Net code.

We will be use distributed testing in JMeter so if we go with REST Endpoints then scaling will be required but scaling is not required in case of executable so I think OS Sampler is better over HTTP request Sampler.
Do you see any concern using OS Sampler over HTTP request Sampler?
Please suggest performance comparison also.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a .NET executable which performs an IOT broker load testing - you don't need JMeter.

If you choosing the way to proceed I would recommend going for HTTP Request samplers as with the OS Process sampler you will have only .NET application execution time while with the HTTP Request samplers you will see:

- [connect time](https://varvy.com/performance/tcp-connection-time.html)
- [latency](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-analyze-results-load-test-using-blazemeter-0/) also known as [time to first byte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_first_byte)
- "pure" [response time](https://help.pingdom.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001228925-Difference-between-Response-Time-and-Page-Load-Time) for each and every HTTP request
- ability to correlate increasing load with changing other metrics like throughput, server hits per second, response time, etc. using [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)

Comment: We are having .Net methods( piece of code to send data to IOT hub). This code is not able to do load test. We are not sure we should create OS Sampler or HTTP sampler to call that .Net method via JMeter.